# Parallel States Merge the output in Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Is it possible to have following kind of Step Function graph, i.e. from 2 parallel state output, one combined state:

[image]

If yes, what would json for this looks like? If not, why?

Answer (score 22):

A parallel task *always* outputs an array (containing one entry per branch).

You can tell AWS step functions to append the output into new (or existing) property in  the original input with `"ResultPath": "$.ParallelOut"` in your parallel state definition, but this is not what you seem to be trying to achieve.

To *merge* the output of parallel task, you can leverage the `"Type": "Pass"` state to define transformations to apply to the JSON document.

For example, in the state machine below, I'm transforming a JSON array...

```
[
  {
    "One": 1,
    "Two": 2
  },
  {
    "Foo": "Bar",
    "Hello": "World"
  }
]
```

...into a few properties

```
{
  "Hello": "World",
  "One": 1,
  "Foo": "Bar",
  "Two": 2
}
```

[image: Transform an array into properties with AWS Step Functions]

```
{
    "Comment": "How to convert an array into properties",
    "StartAt": "warm-up",
    "States": {
      "warm-up": {
        "Type": "Parallel",
        "Next": "array-to-properties",
        "Branches": [
          {
            "StartAt": "numbers",
            "States": {
              "numbers": {
                "Type": "Pass",
                "Result": {
                    "One": 1,
                    "Two" : 2
                },
                "End": true
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "StartAt": "words",
            "States": {
              "words": {
                "Type": "Pass",
                "Result": {
                    "Foo": "Bar",
                    "Hello": "World"
                },
                "End": true
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "array-to-properties": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "Parameters": {
          "One.$": "$[0].One",
          "Two.$": "$[0].Two",
          "Foo.$": "$[1].Foo",
          "Hello.$": "$[1].Hello"
        },
        "End": true
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. If you're using YAML to describe the state machine on Serverless framework, make sure you don't use '-' for each parameter, since this will make an individual object for each.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the output from the `numbers` step will come at 0 index only, the outputs in the resulting array can be shuffled as well right?

Comment: agree with @techytushar is there any documentation that guaranteed that?

Comment: @techytushar yes it does maintain the order. See https://states-language.net/spec.html#parallel-state

Comment: TL;DR (from above documentation) - `The elements of the output array correspond to the branches in the same order that they appear in the "Branches" array`

Answer (score 12):

It is possible as opposed diagram below

[image]

The parallel state should look like this

```
"MyParallelState": {
  "Type": "Parallel",
  "InputPath": "$",
  "OutputPath": "$",
  "ResultPath": "$.ParallelResultPath",
  "Next": "SetCartCompleteStatusState",
  "Branches": [
    {
      "StartAt": "UpdateMonthlyUsageState",
      "States": {
        "UpdateMonthlyUsageState": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "InputPath": "$",
          "OutputPath": "$",
          "ResultPath": "$.UpdateMonthlyUsageResultPath",
          "Resource": "LambdaARN",
          "End": true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "StartAt": "QueueTaxInvoiceState",
      "States": {
        "QueueTaxInvoiceState": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "InputPath": "$",
          "OutputPath": "$",
          "ResultPath": "$.QueueTaxInvoiceResultPath",
          "Resource": "LambdaARN",
          "End": true
        }
      }
    }
```

The output of `MyParallelState` will be populated as in array, from each state in the `Parallel state`. They are populated within `ParallelResultPath` object and will be passed into the Next state

```
{
  "ParallelResultPath": [
    {
      "UpdateMonthlyUsageResultPath": Some Output
    },
    {
      "QueueTaxInvoiceResultPath": Some Output
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use ResultSelector and Result Path to combine the result into one object

We have a parallel state like:

```
{
  "StartAt": "ParallelBranch",
  "States": {
    "ParallelBranch": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "ResultPath": "$",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "OutputPath": "$",
      "ResultSelector": {
        "UsersResult.$": "$[1].UsersUpload",
        "CustomersResult.$": "$[0].customersDataUpload"
      },
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "customersDataUpload",
          "States": {
            "customersDataUpload": {
              "Type": "Pass",
              "ResultPath": "$.customersDataUpload.Output",
              "Result": {
                "CompletionStatus": "success",
                "CompletionDetails": null
              },
              "Next": "Wait2"
            },
            "Wait2": {
              "Comment": "A Wait state delays the state machine from continuing for a specified time.",
              "Type": "Wait",
              "Seconds": 2,
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "UsersUpload",
          "States": {
            "UsersUpload": {
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Result": {
                "CompletionStatus": "success",
                "CompletionDetails": null
              },
              "ResultPath": "$.UsersUpload.Output",
              "Next": "Wait1"
            },
            "Wait1": {
              "Comment": "A Wait state delays the state machine from continuing for a specified time.",
              "Type": "Wait",
              "Seconds": 1,
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    }
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 129600,
  "Version": "1.0"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YilYI.png)

And the output will be like:

```
{
  "UsersResult": {
    "Output": {
      "CompletionStatus": "success",
      "CompletionDetails": null
    }
  },
  "CustomersResult": {
    "Output": {
      "CompletionStatus": "success",
      "CompletionDetails": null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If suppoe one branch job fails will it wait for other job as well or will the branch fail at once

Comment: By default, all branches will fail immediately if one branch job fails.

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram is technically wrong because no state can set multiple states to its `Next` task. You cannot start State Machine as `StartAt` by providing multiple State names. Also, even if it was possible I don't see any point why would you want to run two parallel states as opposed to one parallel state with all the sub states that you would split into two.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
        "Transform And Freeze": {
          "Type": "Parallel",
          "InputPath": "$",
          "Branches": [
            {
              "StartAt": "Transform Status",
              "States": {
                "Transform Status": {
                  "Type": "Map",
                  "ItemsPath": "$",
                  "MaxConcurrency": 25,
                  "Iterator": {
                    "StartAt": "Transform",
                    "States": {
                      "Transform": {
                        "Type": "Task",
                        "Resource": "${TransformFunction}",
                        "End": true
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "End": true
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "StartAt": "Freeze Status",
              "States": {
                "Freeze Status": {
                  "Type": "Map",
                  "MaxConcurrency": 25,
                  "Iterator": {
                    "StartAt": "Freeze",
                    "States": {
                      "Freeze Transactions": {
                        "Type": "Task",
                        "Resource": "${FreezeFunction}",
                        "End": true
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "End": true
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "ResultPath" : "$.parts",
          "Next": "SetParallelOutput",
          "Catch": [
            {
              "ErrorEquals": [
                "States.ALL"
              ],
              "ResultPath": "$.exception",
              "Next": "Error Handler"
            }
          ]
        },
        "SetParallelOutput": {
          "Type": "Pass",
          "Parameters": {
            "foo.$": "$.foo",
            "bar.$": "$.bar",
            "parts.$": "$.parts[0]"
          },
          "Next": "Target Type"
        },
```

[image]