# Can AWS Step Function depend on concurrent Lambdas completing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am attempting to find a way to have a **Parent** Lambda function invoke multiple concurrent parameterized **Child** Lambda functions, and have another **Final** Lambda function execute once all of the **Child** Lambda functions have completed.

The goal is for the **Child** functions to write data to S3, and for the **Final** function to import the data from S3 to a database.

Is this possible using Step Functions? If so, how? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parallel States Merge the output in Step Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105792/parallel-states-merge-the-output-in-step-function)

Comment: That's close, except I need to be able to dynamically invoke multiple concurrent Child functions using the output of the Parent task, rather than explicitly defining each Child function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with Step functions. You will need to use a [Map state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) in your state machine.

[Here is an AWS Blog post about the Map state that gives examples of it's usage when it was first announced.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-step-functions-support-for-dynamic-parallelism/)

Comment: This looks like it's probably what I need, going to look into it further, thanks!