# Can we send output from 1 branch to another in parallel type step function execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

[image]

I need the output from that 2nd branch to be included as input to 1st branch's next step. Like multiple inheritance just check the diagram to get clear picture.

Comment: I would like to do same.  Did you find an answer?  Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54105792/parallel-states-merge-the-output-in-step-function says you can add output into input, which seems like that might work, but I have not explored further yet.

Answer (score 0):

You want indeed an inner parallel block to reconciliate the two branches.

Sorry for the bad quality of my drawing.

[image]

And in this specific context, it could also mean that the step should be outside of the parallel block, if you want to have one single parallel block.

Comment: the scenario is in parallel block instead of 2 steps I have 5 out which 1 step has sub-steps inside the parallel block itself. I would like to know if we can pass output from 1 branch to another inside the parallel block itself. I need its output to be considered in one of the sub-steps.

Comment: At present the diagram that I have made lets say it is in production with that 1 arrow missing for which I have asked question. So the output from parallel branches is appended as an array and passed to last block. I would like to know is there any way that we can pass the o/p from right branch which has "End":True to contain "Next": "sub-step of 1st branch".

Comment: No, this does not work like this. What you are mentioning is indeed an inner parallel block inside the parallel block, what I draw. Because if one step (name it Foo) of branch A depends also on result of branch B, then indeed, it means that Foo is not in branch A but indeed is a child of A & B, so the step after the parallelism between A and B ends.